# What does 'cutoff' mean in SCIP?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, scip, sat

What does `cutoff` mean in SCIP? I see the term `cutoff bound` but am unsure what a `cutoff` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the node was pruned since it's dual bound is exceeding the best known primal bound.

Comment: i.e. the solver has proved that any node descended from the pruned node will be worse than the current known solution, so there would be no point in exploring that path any further